# How to convert a CSV file with strange delimiter to a dataframe in Python using pandas library

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to convert a CSV file to a dataframe using Python but the delimiter is causing issues.

The CSV file is an output from a software that arrange the data into a single line mainly separated by: ","

There are only two lines in the CSV file. The first one is:

```
Date,"  2015-01-30","   2015-01-31","   2015-02-01","   2015-02-02","   2015-02-03","   2015-02-04","   2015-02-05","   2015-02-06","
```

And the second one is:

```
Amount,"14000.030000000002","13500.650000000001","26200.15000000001","33000.38000000002","38000.31000000003","29000.670000000013","29000.920000000016","31000.360000000015"
```

This is the code I wrote thus far:

```
data = pd.read_csv("csv_file_one_line.csv", sep = '","' , engine = 'python')
data.stack(level=0)
```

This is the output I arrive at:

```
0  "Date,""\t2019-01-30"    "Amount,""14000.030000000002"
   "\t2019-01-31"                    "13500.650000000001"
   "\t2019-02-01"                     "26200.15000000001"
   "\t2019-02-02"                     "33000.38000000002"
   "\t2019-02-03"                     "38000.31000000003"
   "\t2019-02-04"                    "29000.670000000013"
   "\t2019-02-05"                    "29000.920000000016"
   "\t2019-02-06"                  "31000.360000000015"""
dtype: object
```

The expected results would be a clean dataframe with two columns with the header Date and Amount respectively. From there, I would work my way to a predictive model using ARIMA.

Comment: this is normal CVS file and separator is `,`, not `","`. CSV sometimes put value in `" "` but it is normal and pandas should read it with standard settings.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the separator is just a comma, with most (but not all) values surrounded by quotes.  How was this CSV created?  It seems like the rows/columns have been transposed.

Comment: the only problem makes `,"` at the end of first line. So you could first read file as normal text, remove `,"` from first line, save it as normal text file and after that use `read_csv` with standard separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a little more sophisticated regex expression:

```
df=pd.read_csv(ff,sep=r',"\s*|","\s*',engine="python")


     Date  2015-01-30  2015-01-31  2015-02-01  ...  2015-02-04  2015-02-05           2015-02-06  Unnamed: 9
0  Amount    14000.03    13500.65    26200.15  ...    29000.67    29000.92  31000.360000000015"         NaN

[1 rows x 10 columns]


df= df.drop(columns="Date").stack().droplevel(0).reset_index()


        index                    0
0  2015-01-30                14000
1  2015-01-31              13500.6
2  2015-02-01              26200.2
3  2015-02-02              33000.4
4  2015-02-03              38000.3
5  2015-02-04              29000.7
6  2015-02-05              29000.9
7  2015-02-06  31000.360000000015"

df.columns=["Date","Amount"]
df.iloc[-1,-1]= np.float64(df.iloc[-1,-1].rstrip('"'))

         Date              Amount
0  2015-01-30               14000
1  2015-01-31             13500.6
2  2015-02-01             26200.2
3  2015-02-02             33000.4
4  2015-02-03             38000.3
5  2015-02-04             29000.7
6  2015-02-05             29000.9
7  2015-02-06             31000.4
```

**EDIT:**
Or read the file and convert ',' and '"' to whitespaces, and use StringIO to read the data.
The separators are now whitespaces only.

```
import io,re

with open("data.csv") as ff:
   text=re.sub(r'[,"]',' ', ff.read())

f2= io.StringIO(text)
df=pd.read_csv(f2, sep=r'\s+',engine="python")

Date  2015-01-30  2015-01-31  2015-02-01  2015-02-02  2015-02-03  2015-02-04  2015-02-05  2015-02-06
0  Amount    14000.03    13500.65    26200.15    33000.38    38000.31    29000.67    29000.92    31000.36

etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line - `data = pd.read_csv("csv_file_one_line.csv", sep = '","' , engine = 'python')`, you are separating based on `','`, not simply `,`.

Just use the comma, not apostrophes and a comma.

Answer (score 0):

This data would be normal CSV file but problem is `,"` at the end of first line.

So reading it as normal text and removing `,"` in first line I create correct CSV file

```
with open('input.csv') as f1, open('output.txt', 'w') as f2:
    for row in f1:
        row = row.rstrip('\n')
        if row.endswith(',"'):
            row = row[:-2]
        f2.write(row+'\n')
```

After that I can read it using standard settings

```
df = pd.read_csv("output.txt", header=None)
```

but it gives

```
        0                   1  ...                   7                   8
0    Date          2015-01-30  ...          2015-02-05          2015-02-06
1  Amount  14000.030000000002  ...  29000.920000000016  31000.360000000015

[2 rows x 9 columns]
```

After transposition

```
df = df.T
```

I get

```
                0                   1
0           Date              Amount
1     2015-01-30  14000.030000000002
2     2015-01-31  13500.650000000001
3     2015-02-01   26200.15000000001
4     2015-02-02   33000.38000000002
5     2015-02-03   38000.31000000003
6     2015-02-04  29000.670000000013
7     2015-02-05  29000.920000000016
8     2015-02-06  31000.360000000015
```

After that I can use first row as names for columns, and remove this row

```
df = df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0])
df = df.drop(0)
```

Result:

```
            Date              Amount
1     2015-01-30  14000.030000000002
2     2015-01-31  13500.650000000001
3     2015-02-01   26200.15000000001
4     2015-02-02   33000.38000000002
5     2015-02-03   38000.31000000003
6     2015-02-04  29000.670000000013
7     2015-02-05  29000.920000000016
8     2015-02-06  31000.360000000015
```